# PyTorch DataLoader shuffle

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, shuffle, training-data

I did an experiment and I did not get the result I was expecting.

For the first part, I am using

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=128, 
                                          shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
```

I save `trainloader.dataset.targets` to the variable `a`, and `trainloader.dataset.data` to the variable `b` before training my model. Then, I train the model using `trainloader`. 
After the training is finished, I save `trainloader.dataset.targets` to the variable `c`, and `trainloader.dataset.data` to the variable `d`. Finally, I check `a == c` and `b == d` and they both give `True`, which was expected because the shuffle parameter of the `DataLoader` is `False`.

For the second part, I am using

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=128, 
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
```

I save `trainloader.dataset.targets` to the variable `e`, and `trainloader.dataset.data` to the variable `f` before training my model. Then, I train the model using `trainloader`. After the training is finished, I save `trainloader.dataset.targets` to the variable `g`, and `trainloader.dataset.data` to the variable `h`. I expect `e == g` and `f == h` to be both `False` since `shuffle=True`, but they give `True` again. What am I missing from the definition of `DataLoader` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the data that is stored directly in the trainloader.dataset.data or .target will not be shuffled, the data is only shuffled when the DataLoader is called as a generator or as iterator

You can check it by doing next(iter(trainloader)) a few times without shuffling and with shuffling and they should give different results

```
import torch
import torchvision

transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
        torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
        ])
MNIST_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('~/Desktop/intern/',download = True, train = False,
                                           transform = transform)
dataLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(MNIST_dataset,
                                         batch_size = 128,
                                         shuffle = False,
                                         num_workers = 10)
target = dataLoader.dataset.targets


MNIST_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('~/Desktop/intern/',download = True, train = False,
                                           transform = transform)

dataLoader_shuffled= torch.utils.data.DataLoader(MNIST_dataset,
                                         batch_size = 128,
                                         shuffle = True,
                                         num_workers = 10)

target_shuffled = dataLoader_shuffled.dataset.targets

print(target == target_shuffled)

_, target = next(iter(dataLoader));
_, target_shuffled = next(iter(dataLoader_shuffled))

print(target == target_shuffled)
```

This will give :

```
tensor([True, True, True,  ..., True, True, True])
tensor([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
        False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])
```

However the data and label stored in data and target is a fixed list and since you are trying to access it directly, they will not be shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue while loading the data using the Dataset class. I stopped loading the data using Dataset class, and instead use the following code which is working fine with me

```
X = torch.from_numpy(X)
y = torch.from_numpy(y)

train_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X, y)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

where X & y are numpy array from csv file.